# Catching HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException Exception

Tags: hibernate

I need to know how can we catch the exception related Hibernate Optimistic locking.
My problem is the exception is not getting caught even though I have put the update statements in the try/catch blocks.My sample code looks like this.

This code is present in the service layer, I am using Spring MVC controllers. Which is the best place to catch this exception? Is it in the controller or in the Service classes?
I tried catching it in the controller, even that didn't work.

What I feel is Hibernate will execute the update queries in its own strategy, by the time it executed the update, the response was already sent from controller.

Please suggest how to catch it and show appropriate message to the user.

```
try
{
//Some code to fetch the object from database
    Employee emp = employeeDao.load(id);
    emp.setName("xyz");
    employeeDao.saveOrUpdate(emp);
}
catch(StaleObjectStateException e)
{
    //TODO: Put the Exception in the response Object
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) logger.debug("Stale Data Exception: Request User to reload the Page");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

catch(HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException e)
{
    //TODO: Put the Exception in the response Object
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) logger.debug("Stale Data Exception: Request User to reload the Page");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //TODO: Put the Exception in the response Object
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) logger.debug("Stale Data Exception: Request User to reload the Page");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```